# C# - JObject.Parse - Invalid JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json.net

I'm working with an API that is returning JSON.

I have a method that calls the api, and parses the JSON response for the desired nodes.

Up to this point everything has been working fine, except the latest JSON response appears to be malformed.

Other responses come back like:

```
{
   "Keyword":"\"marhope\"",
   "TermKey":null,
   "Customers":[
      {
         "Memberships":[ ],
         "CompanyId":0,
         "ObjectId":112974,
         "ObjectType":"Customer",

      }
   ]
}
```

I use JObject.Parse to bring back the appropriate nodes by name.

The latest JSON response comes back as:

```
{
   [
      {
         "AnimalId":9079117,
         "SpeciesCode":"XX",
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no "name", and the JSON is slightly invalid.

How can I parse this. For the first example I was using the code below, but now that the JSON has no "name", I don't know how to approach this, thoughts?

```
JObject results = JObject.Parse(csr.SearchCustomer(1, 1, 870, term));
foreach (var resp in results["Customers"])
{
    string obj = (string)resp["CompanyId"];
}
```

Comment: Well, the API isn't returning valid JSON. I suggest you talk to the developers and get it to return valid JSON instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon Skeet is correct, the second JSON is invalid: you cannot have an array directly inside an object with no property name.  The best course of action is to get the API developers to fix the JSON.  However, if you're just looking for a quick and dirty workaround, you could strip off the the first and last brace from the invalid JSON and then parse it as an array using `JArray.Parse`.

```
string json = @"{
   [
      {
         ""AnimalId"":9079117,
         ""SpeciesCode"":""XX"",
      }
   ]
}";

json = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2);
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach (JObject item in array.Children<JObject>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("AnimalId: " + item["AnimalId"]);
    Console.WriteLine("SpeciesCode: " + item["SpeciesCode"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around, I needed something quick, I'll proceed to speak with the developers, just couldn't wait for them to fix.