# newtonsoft json deserialization error handling: partial deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Is there way to deserialize invalid json?

For example, next JSON deserialization will fail with `JsonReaderException`

```
{
 'sessionId': 's0j1',
 'commandId': 19,
 'options': invalidValue // invalid value
}
```

because `options` property value is invalid.

Is there a nice way to get `sessionId` and `commandId` values even if `options` value is invalid?

I know it's possible to handle errors during deserialization (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm)

```
var json = "{'sessionId': 's0j1', 'commandId': 19, 'options': invalidValue}"; 

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
    {
      args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
});
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);
```

Bit it will result in `result = null`.

Comment: I don't think Json.NET can handle invalid Json. If you want to parse something that is not Json, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29146482/579895)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [`JsonReader`](https://newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm).

Example code:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(yourJsonString)))
{
    var lastProp = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
            {
                lastProp = reader.Value.ToString();
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer || 
                reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            {
                result.Add(lastProp, reader.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    catch(JsonReaderException jre)
    {
        //do anything what you want with exception
    }
}
```

Note, that there is `try..catch` block as when `JsonReader` meets invalid character it throws `JsonReaderException` on `reader.Read()`